# How do I determine which power managment tool is blanking the screen?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm using Mint 16. In power management settings, put display to sleep is set to never.
I have also uninstalled all of the screen saver packages.

Yet, after 10 minutes the screen goes blank.

How do I determine which process or program is doing this?

Comment: Is the machine going into a different power state, rather than the screensaver blanking the screen?

Comment: That's why I'm trying to figure out. Music continues to play, the monitors appear to go into standby (their power lights change color), so I don't think is just a black screen screensaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xset` command (from a terminal/xterm/whatever) to turn off the default X11 system screensaver. (Yes, *another* screensaver setting... this one is a *feature* from days of yore)

- show current settings:

  ```
  xset q
  ```
- turn screensaver off

  ```
  xset s off
  ```
- set screensaver delay to 30 minutes

  ```
  xset s 1800
  ```

You should be able to put `xset s off` in your .xinitrc or perhaps in your Window Manager's startup queue.

`xset` can manipulate many more X11 things, but `s` and `q` are my most used options.

You can supply a command-line option to `X` to turn off screen blanking from the beginning, but that can sometimes be more trouble to discover WHERE to add the option.  Honest, it's do-able, just not obvious.

---

As an additional thing, you can disable the blanking of the text/console too (very handy on my Raspberry Pi's with no keyboard attached)

```
    setterm -blank 0
```

This turns off the (also 10 minute!) console blanker.  I place this command in `/etc/rc.local` so it is set during boot, affecting everything thereafter.